# preg_match an url without the sublinks

Tags: php, sql, regex, preg-match

I have an expression which I only want to find `/settings` and not if it contains a sublink like `/settings/test1`

Right now my expression only finds the one which contain a sublink, but not the one I want one.

`^\/settings\/`

`/settings
/settings/test1
/settings/test2`

http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/jPr

Comment: Maybe you want to use `^\/settings$`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thnx, if you post it as answer I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You match sublinks because your pattern contains `/` at the end. You need to remove the `/` and anchor the pattern at the end of the string with the `$` anchor:

Use

```
^\/settings$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LNzCBa/1)